# C# 5.0 Generics: param type inference

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I've always been under impression that the C# compiler is able to infer type params in cases like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMessageBus messageBus = null;

       //Here the compiler nags "type params for Publish cannot be inferred from the usage.. .."
        messageBus.Publish(new CorrectorAdded(10));
    }
}

public interface IEvent<out TPayload>
{
    TPayload Payload { get; }
}

public abstract class EventBase<TPayload> : IEvent<TPayload>
{
    public TPayload Payload { get; private set; }

    protected EventBase(TPayload payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
}

public interface IMessageBus
{
    void Publish<TEvent, TPayload>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent<TPayload>;

    IDisposable Subscribe<TEvent, TPayload>(Action<TPayload> listener) where TEvent : IEvent<TPayload>;
}

public class CorrectorAdded : EventBase<CorrectorAddedArgs>
{
    public CorrectorAdded(CorrectorAddedArgs payload) : base(payload)
    {
    }

    public CorrectorAdded(int correctorId) : this(new CorrectorAddedArgs(correctorId))
    {
    }
}

public class CorrectorAddedArgs
{
    public int CorrectorId { get; private set; }

    public CorrectorAddedArgs(int correctorId)
    {
        CorrectorId = correctorId;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to get the type inference to work in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630690/why-cant-nested-generic-types-be-inferred (not the exact same question, yet the answer by Eric Lippert applies to your question as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface signature for `publish` defines 2 constraints:

```
void Publish<TEvent, TPayload>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent<TPayload>;
```

1. `TEvent` which will be the signature for the method parameter
2. `TPayload` which states `TEvent` must implement the interface `IEvent<TPayload>`

If the Publish method only had the constraint of `TEvent`, then the compiler could infer the usage since the signature of the method already has the type constraint defined, i.e.,

```
void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event);
```

The above would then allow for the method invocation to be used without the type constraint, i.e.,

```
messageBus.Publish( new CorrectorAdded( 10 ) );
// would be the same as
messageBus.Publish<CorrectorAdded>( new CorrectorAdded( 10 ) );
```

However, since the interface defines the 2nd constraint, the compiler has no idea what the intent is for `TPayload` since the event can implement any number of `IEvent<TPayload>`'s. However, if the method signature did include the type of `TPayload` then the complier could actual infer the constraint, i.e.,

```
void Publish<TEvent, TPayload>(TEvent @event, TPayload payload) where TEvent : IEvent<TPayload>;
```

And then then method could be invoked without the type constraints:

```
messageBus.Publish( new CorrectorAdded( 10 ), new FooThatImplementsTPayload() );
```

Comment: Thanks! That cleared all up. Didn't make my life easier, though as the API does look ambiguous this way =). Will need to turn smth around maybe..

Answer (score 0):

To those who are still curious about how an alternative API might look like, here is what I came up with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMessageBus messageBus = null;

        messageBus
            .Event<CorrectorAdded>()
            .Subscribe(eventArgs => { /*skipped*/ });

        //skipped

        messageBus
            .Event<CorrectorAdded>()
            .Publish(new CorrectorAddedArgs(1));
    }
}

public abstract class EventBase
{
    //skipped
}

public abstract class EventBase<TPayload> : EventBase
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(Action<TPayload> listener)
    {
        //skipped
    }

    public void Publish(TPayload payload)
    {
        //skipped
    }
}

public class CorrectorAdded : EventBase<CorrectorAddedArgs>
{
}

public class CorrectorAddedArgs
{
    public int CorrectorId { get; private set; }

    public CorrectorAddedArgs(int correctorId)
    {
        CorrectorId = correctorId;
    }
}

public interface IMessageBus
{
    TEvent Event<TEvent>() where TEvent : EventBase, new();
}
```